# Why dict_force_resize_ratio default is 5 in redis?

Tags: redis

Why **dict_force_resize_ratio** default is **5** in redis/dict.c?

Comment: I don't think this is a bad question at all. I think it would have helped if you would have provided some context on why this matters to your use case. But even as it stands, I did not feel it was a question that deserved so many down votes.

Comment: Why doesn't dict_force_resize_ratio use other numbers? Is it because the test results indicate that 5 is the best performance?

Comment: Maybe this is related to the default size of dict for 4?

Answer (score 0):

It is a heuristic, there is no right or wrong answer.

`dict_force_resize_ratio` is the ratio between the number of elements in the dictionary to the size (aka number of buckets). Normally, redis will resize the hashtable whenever this ratio is 1.

However if resizing is turned off and the dictionary keeps growing. At one point, it will degenerate to an array, and time complexity will become O(n). By having an upper bound of 5, redis ensures that the hashtable performance will not degrade to O(n).